# Can one change claims when applying a national stage application using a PCT application?

Tags: claims, pct

My PCT application has more than 100 claims.

I wanna have the strongest protection possible in some countries whereas in others I need some limited protection. [I don't want to waste too much money in claims]

For example, Can I able to remove some claims while applying to USPTO using a PCT application? Or it has to be amended later, after filing the USPTO application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the claims can be amended anytime before first office action. Also, One can reduce number of claims to reduce cost while demand for excess fee payment is pending.

Ref [1](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1893.html) 1893.01 (e) Commencement and Entry

Ref [2](https://mpep.uspto.gov/RDMS/MPEP/e8r9#/e8r9/d0e86256.html)